# Not able to set incremental transfer mode for scheduled flow with Salesforce integration

Tags: amazon-s3, salesforce, amazon-appflow

As per the documentation (provided link below) we should get option to set the transfer mode, but not able to see the option.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appflow/latest/userguide/flow-triggers.html

Do we need to enable any setting before we get this option or permission issue?
[image]
Thanks

Gone through documentation details and few posts like shown here - [AWS Appflow | Incremental transfer not working | Simulation check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75134252/aws-appflow-incremental-transfer-not-working-simulation-check)
We can see that Incremental Mode is available but I cant see that option.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aufX.png